# Microsoft.ReportViewer : How to upgrade Version from 8 to 11

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer2008

I have developed an c# desktop app on Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft Sql server 2012. When i deploy this app on my client system which has sql server 2008, app is running correctly but reports are not working. It throws exception:

**Could find the file or assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common V 11.0.0.0**

When i see the assembly it has V 8.0.0.0. My question is how to upgrade this to V 11 without installing Sql server 2012 ? Is there any way to copy the new version files in assembly ?

Comment: use the 2010 report viewer in your app instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There is a **runtime** available for the report viewer.

You need to download and install the following two files:

- Microsoft System CLR Types for Microsoft SQL Server 2012 ([x86](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239643&clcid=0x409), [x64](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239644&clcid=0x409))
- [Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747)

(Don't mind that the first file has "SQL Server 2012" in its name. It's just a tiny library with a scary name required by the Report Viewer Runtime. It won't actually install SQL Server 2012. More details can be found in the "System Requirements" section of the Report Viewer Runtime link.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the great solution